# Python adaBoost all predicts are same class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, adaboost

```
### my dataset
import pandas as pd
csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ga59wig/419B/main/data.csv?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACKSAONPXCVHO2L4IGQCID72ZK3422Q'
gdf = pd.read_csv(csv_url)

gdf = gdf.dropna()

#for accuracy_score
from sklearn import metrics as metrics

# for train_test_split
from sklearn import model_selection as model_selection

# For the classifier
from sklearn import ensemble as ensemble 

cols = gdf.columns
cols = cols[1:]

x = gdf[cols].values
y = gdf["Relative Height bin98 (cm)"]

print(y)
print(x)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1569)

adaBoost_model = ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=200, learning_rate=1e-05)
adaBoost_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
adaBoost_prediction = adaBoost_model.predict(x_test)

adaBoost_accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(adaBoost_prediction, y_test)
adaBoost_confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(adaBoost_prediction, y_test)
adaBoost_classification_report = metrics.classification_report(adaBoost_prediction, y_test)

print("Accuracy:", adaBoost_accuracy)
print(adaBoost_confusion_matrix)
print(adaBoost_classification_report)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Accuracy: 0.4168228190714137
[[8008 3144 4233 3827]
 [   0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     3 - 6 m       1.00      0.42      0.59     19212
    6 - 10 m       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
        <3 m       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
      > 10 m       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

    accuracy                           0.42     19212
   macro avg       0.25      0.10      0.15     19212
weighted avg       1.00      0.42      0.59     19212
```

I'm new to ML in Python and have some trouble causing an error in my data or my code. I get only one class in my predicts. The accuracy is always the same (because of that I assume). What am I doing wrong?

I tried already:

- setting learning_rate to a low value
- converting y to integer
- checking my data
- with 'iris' example data it's working

Answer (score 1):

The data looks a bit suspect to me...a histogram plot indicates that even though the dataset has about 100k rows, most are duplicates:

[image]

```
gdf.hist(grid=False, bins=50)
plt.tight_layout()
```

This is confirmed by counting up the unique rows. In the table below, even though about 41k (almost half) the data set falls under the `y=3-6m` label, you can see that they are duplicates of merely 4 unique values. To me it seems like something has gone amiss with a prior processing step for the data, and I think that'd be the place to start looking.

[image]

```
gdf.groupby('Relative Height bin98 (cm)').value_counts().to_frame()
```

Comment: I corrected the data. I didn't look in it deeply enough
`csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ga59wig/419B/main/speichern.csv'
gdf = pd.read_csv(csv_url)`

but still I only get to classes predicted. At least accuracy is about 60% now.

Comment: Not all rows are unique, just a few are not now. So I assume this is not the source of the problem.